# Can't use Spring ApplicationListener

Tags: spring, listener

My project is Spring-boot(1.3.5 RELEASE),Web Project(Spring-Web 4.3.0 REALESE).
I want to use the "ApplicationListener",when spring was loaded,to do something.But my code doesn't work.There's my code:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

public class BootListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Spring启动监听器");
    System.out.println(event.getTimestamp());
  }
}

package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: If you want to use a listener then you should add it somewhere in the spring that recognizes its existence   along the spring boot application startup.

Comment: Right,I roget to annotated the class as a spring bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your event listener a singleton so Spring can pick this up. Annotate your `BootListener` with `@Component`.

To publish events yourself, inject `ApplicationEventPublisher`.

Comment: Correct! I just roget the annotation.